# Count issue in Mysql

Tags: mysql-5.5

I query a table

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sf_guard_user_group
```

return count 1 but table has total 28 records. But if I test it via putty from another machine, it shows count 28. Help to sort out.

[image]

Comment: You missed the `FROM` :)

Comment: true, it might alias the count(*) and return 1. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> I query a table "Select count(*) from sf_guard_user_group"

That's not true, according to the screenshot. I don't see the `FROM` clause there.